# Jquery in MVC2 Areas ($ is not defined)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, master-pages

I'm becoming desperate by using MVC 2 areas. I've got a MVC 2 application. One part of this application is a area called "Marked". All the views in my application have the same Masterpage.
My Masterpage is lacted in my main application and the head looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../Content/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script src="../../../../Scripts/NewFolder1/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/NewFolder1/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 50px;
        height: 34px;
    }
</style>
```

In the Index page of my mainapplication I enter this code and a beautiful tab controll appears:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        // Tabs
        $('#tabs').tabs();

        //hover states on the static widgets
        $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
            );

    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo page css*/
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    </style>    


    <!-- Tabs -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Tabs</h2>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>

            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>

    </div>
```

But when I enter the same in a page of my area every firebug shows a exception: **"$ is not defined"**

It must be something with my routing, my are registration looks like this:

```
  context.MapRoute("Market with language", "{culture}/Market/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        }, new { culture = "de|en" });
```

Firebug shows this request in red:`http://localhost:12737/de/Scripts/NewFolder1/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js`

My structure looks like this:

```
    Mainapplication
    -scripts
    --folder1
    ---jsscripts
    -views
--shared
    ---masterpage.aspx
    -areas
    --market
    ---views
----viewone.apsx
```

Thanks for all your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scripts are not being resolved, probably a routing/linking issue using the relative paths in your example. You can confirm by checking the console output of Firebug/Fiddler.

Try using the `ResolveUrl` method.

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/NewFolder1/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, but it does not work. I have tried to use ResolveUrl, but the output of firebug is the same: $ is not definied. If I use paths from the internet, like this:  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> every thing works fine... any more ideas?

Comment: I am pretty confident it is the path. Have you checked Firebug or Fiddler to ensure that the HTTP request for you jQuery file is successful?

Comment: I'm using firebug, how to find out if the http request is successful?

Comment: In the `Net` tab, when you load a page it will show all the requests with their status.

Comment: thanks, you are right: the requests are red marked! pleas check my edited question.

Comment: What is the URL of you home page? I ask because with the URL you show in your edit you would have had to put the `de` in your `ResolveUrl` or it is in a virtual directory called `de`.

Comment: it's not online, it's just an offline project, hosted by vs2010 delepment server. The url looks like this http://localhost:12737/de/Market/ars/cube or http://localhost:12737/en/Market/ars/cube

Comment: with the is your scripts folder in the same level as you `de` and `en` areas?

Comment: de and en are no areas I just use them to get the culture of the user.

Comment: Thanks I found my problem! Your idea of using ResolveUrl was right. The fail was just the wrong name of the java script... I have tried 1000 things but do not think about a correct name! Thanks!!!